# Using different dataframes to change column values - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe1 like the following:

```
A  B   C   D  
1 111  a   9
2 121  b   8
3 122  c   7
4 121  d   6
5 131  e   5
```

Also, I have another dataframe2:

```
   Code   String
    111     s
    12      b
    13      u
```

What I want is to creat a dataframe like the following:

```
A  B   C   D  
1 111  S   9
2 121  b   8
3 122  c   7
4 121  b   6
5 131  u   5
```

That would be, take the first n digits  (where n is the number of digits in Code column of dataframe2) and if it has the same numbers that the code, then the column C in dataframe1 would change for the string in dataframe2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ? The code is not very neat but work..

```
import pandas as pd 
DICT=df2.set_index('Code').T.to_dict('list')

Temp=[]

for key, value in DICT.items():
    n=len(str(key))
    D1={str(key):value[0]}
    T=df1.B.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:n]).map(D1)

    Temp2=(df1.B.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:n]))
    Tempdf=pd.DataFrame({'Ori':df1.B,'Now':Temp2,'C':df1.C})
    TorF=(Tempdf.groupby(['Now'])['Ori'].transform(min) == Tempdf['Ori'])

    for n, i in enumerate(T):
        if TorF[n]==False:
            T[n]=Tempdf.ix[n,0]
    Temp.append(T)
df1.C=pd.DataFrame(data=Temp).fillna(method='bfill').T.ix[:,0]

Out[255]: 
   A    B  C  D
0  1  111  s  9
1  2  121  b  8
2  3  122  c  7
3  4  121  b  6
4  5  131  u  5
```

Comment: Sorry It took long! Worked perfectly! Is there a way to improove it's computational cost?

Comment: I'm sorry, im having a problem with the code. And actually you can see it in the output. In row number 3, B is 122 and C is b when it should be c.

Comment: i also confused by this part when i generated this solution yesterday, when we using key 12 --> b, n should be 2 , and we should subset string in df1.B with n=2 right ? 
then 122  will be 12 and we should change c to b

Comment: That's the thing, It should be 'b' unless there is another one that has 12 and another number, like 122 and in that case it should be 'c' (with n=3).

Comment: For example, if you have 127 but in the second dataframe there is no Code 127, you take it as if was 12, therefore 'b'. If there is, like 122 you take it as 122, therefore 'c'

Comment: Sorry for late reply , Just finish my task ~ I update my solution

Comment: Au contraire ! Thank you very much!